# Running app despite build errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build

tl;dr: Is it possible to force the build to run despite all the errors?

For instance, I have a number of classes using some function. I've changed the number of parameters of the function, and edited one of the classes, which will serve as a testing ground. I'm sure that the application won't run into the other `.java` and crash, so fixing errors in them is purely for the Android Studio to allow the build to run. Can I override this block or do I have to waste my time with fixes?

Comment: If the only answer you'll get is "is not possible", the fastest thing to do is to create a new method to call only from the tested code and left the original method for all the other cases.

Comment: ...That is true